# Almost sure convergence of the maximum of iid exponential radom variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be independent exponential random variables with density $Exp(1)$. Let $$Y_n = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i$$
Show that $$\frac{Y_n}{\log n} \rightarrow 1 \;\; \text{almost surely}$$

I can show that $\frac{Y_n}{\log n} \rightarrow 1 \;\; \text{in probability}$ but have no idea how to show the almost sure convergence.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you compute the distribution of the maximum of i.i.d. exponentials? I think after you can figure that out, you can apply the Borel Cantelli lemma to prove that $Y_n/\log n$ exceeds $1 + \epsilon$ only a finite number of times almost surely, then that it drops below $1 - \epsilon$ almost surely a finite number of times, for arbitrary $\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, the limit is proven.

Comment: Yes, I think the distribution of max of iid exponents can be found easily, i.e $P(Y_n<x) = P(x_1<x,\ldots,x_n<x) = (1-e^{-x})^n$, but I am not sure how to proceed with Borel Cantelli lemma. I also tried similar techniques in the proof of SLLN (truncation + subsequence) but still didn't quite get there.

Comment: Commenting here because I have struggled a lot. $P(M_n / \log n > 1 + \epsilon \; i. o.) = 0$ part follows from discussion of $X_n$, and $P(M_n / \log n <= 1 - \epsilon \; i. o.) = 0$ needs some meddling for computing bounds of $\sum_n P(M_n / \log n <= 1 - \epsilon )$.